# How to adjust volume using batch files

Tags: batch-file, volume-mixer

I want to know how to set volume with cmd but can't download software.
I know it is possible because I had it but deleted it. opps

Answer (score 0):

Save this as a .VBS file and use as a template to do what you want. You can find more help about the SendKeys method [here](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html).

```
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "%SystemRoot%\System32\SndVol.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.AppActivate "Volume Mixer"
WshShell.SendKeys "{PGUP}" ' Turn the volume up by 20. If muted it will unmute it.
WshShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"  ' Alt+F4
```

You can call it from a batch file using `cscript SetVol.vbs` (or whatever name you used obviously).